# String and Variable concatenation in Label Tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, string-concatenation

I know; this question has been asked several times already, but after looking through many questions I still can't get it to work. I have a `modalPopupextender` which opens up a `Panel` as seen in code below:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlRename" Style="display: none;" runat="server">
    <div class="Popup radius" style="width: 400px;">
      <div class="PopupHead PageEntry radiusTop">
         <asp:Label ID="lblRename" runat="server" 
             Text='<%= "Rename " + TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text %>'></asp:Label>
      </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

I want `"Rename " + TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text`'s value to show up in the `Text` of `lblRename` but I am getting exactly what I typed:
 i.e. `"Rename " + TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text` and not its `value`.

Answer (score 3):

Move the `Rename` outside of the `<% %>` tags.

`Text='Rename'+<%= Treeview1.SelectedNode.Text %>`

Comment: It is giveing the string (i.e. Rename <%= Treeview1.SelectedNode.Text %>) not the actual value

Comment: Do you need the `+`? Would `Text='Rename <%= Treeview1.SelectedNode.Text %>'` work?